# Wagtail form builder: How to preserve query string/url parameter from form page for corresponding landing page?

Tags: django, wagtail, formbuilder

In a wagtail project with a wagtail form builder [1] the default implementation redirects the user after successful form submission to a landing page [2].

In my somewhat customized implementation of my form page (`AbstractEmailForm`) I use a query string (here: `?embed=true`) to adjust the rendered page/layout for being "embeddable" (via an iFrame). That works.

But after submitting the form on such a page, the method `render_landing_page`[3] gets called and renders a landing page for that form. But my query string is lost. This method could be overridden:

```py
class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):

    def render_landing_page(self, request, form_submission=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Renders the landing page.
        You can override this method to return a different HttpResponse as
        landing page. E.g. you could return a redirect to a separate page.
        """
        
        # !!!Pseudocode (next line):
        # How to get the query string from the form page?
        query_string_from_formpage = get_query_string_from_formpage_request()

        context = self.get_context(request)
        context['form_submission'] = form_submission

        response = TemplateResponse(
            request,
            self.get_landing_page_template(request),
            context
        )

        # !!! Pseudocode (next line):
        # How to pass the captured query string to 
        # this response object?
        response = response + query_string_from_formpage

        return response
```

How do I preserve the query strings from the form page to the corresponding landing page?

[1] https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/forms/index.html
[2] https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/forms/customisation.html#custom-landing-page-redirect
[3] https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/571b9e1918861bcbe64a9005a4dc65f3a1fe7a15/wagtail/contrib/forms/models.py#L270

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution:

<strike>check the http referer of the django request object and act according to this.
In my case I've added a variable to the `render_landing_page` `TemplateResponse` context.</strike>

Check the `GET` parameter, add a corresponding variable to the request context and use this variable in the `form action`:

```py
# models.py
class FormPage(*various mixins*, AbstractEmailForm):
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['embed'] = request.GET.get('embed')
        return context
```

```html
<form 
  action="{% pageurl self %}?embed={{ embed }}"
  method="POST"
>
```